# Sharepoint 2010 Multiple People Picker to List item

Tags: 2010, list, item, person

I have been trying to solve this issue now for countless hours.

here is my senerio:

I have a list A and List B.

List A has a people picker field that allows multiple people to be chosen.

```
     For example the people picker would have John Doe; Jane Doe.
```

What I am trying to accomplish is create a new item in list B for each person from the people picker from list A.

```
     For Example list B would look like the following:
     ID  Name
     1   John Doe
     2   Jane Doe
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: SharePoint does not have tools to do this out of the box. You would need to write custom code. Essentially, you'd have to loop through all values in the people field and create a new item in list B for each person found. That kind of loop cannot be done with a workflow. You might be able to do it with SPServices (google it) if you know JavaScrip and jQuery. If not, you'd need a developer to write an event handler, i.e. custom .Net code.